# Why won't my display block reappear?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a on-click event on javascript for my website and once the heading is clicked the block of information shows. That part works. However once I click it again it does not go back to "none".

```
var x = 1;

if(x%2 != 0){

    document.getElementById("infoForEmployers").style.display = "block";
    x++;

}else{

    document.getElementById("infoForEmployers").style.display = "none";
    x++;

}

console.log(x);
```

Never mind the console log, that was me trying to see if x was increasing. So basically every other click should either show or not show.

Comment: If all of the code is in a function, then `x` is initialized to `1` every time the function is executed.

Comment: ah I see, how would I work around that?

Comment: Move `var x = 1;` outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your x variable is being set to 1 every time you set the function.

Make it a global variable and you'll be fine:

Try this:

```
window.x =  window.x || 0 ;

if(window.x%2 != 0){
    document.getElementById("infoForEmployers").style.display = "block";
    window.x++;
}else{

    document.getElementById("infoForEmployers").style.display = "none";
    window.x++;
}

console.log(window.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to toggle the element

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```